# understand tomcat HTTP connector port from JMX MBeans

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I am connecting to tomcat over JMX. I wrote a simple JMX client to connect to
tomcat and read different JMX MBean attributes to monitor tomcat. My problem is, I would like to know which port tomcat's HTTP connector is listenting. Is there a way to get this details over JMX Mbean - without reading the server.xml file of tomcat. But to get it thru some attributes of one MBean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MBean is called something like `Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=http-8080`. As you can see the connector port is in the name.

Comment: If the tomcat is not running on 8080, and it is running on 9090 - then the name of the bean will become Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=http-9090. 
In that case, I need to know which port the http connector is running.

Comment: In that case it is running on port 9090. The name of the threadpool reflects the port of the http conector.

Comment: Probably one stupid question - but my question is - is there any way to know the names of the beans programatically that tomcat exposes ?

Comment: You can use the JConsole utility to inspect all MBeans of a running application.

Comment: You can get a list of MBeans matching various criteria using the `MBeanServerConnection.queryNames()` method.  For example, `queryNames(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=ThreadPool,*", null))` should return a list of all the `ThreadPool` MBeans.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated MBean for each connector. You can alls those MBean's ObjectNames by querying for `*:type=Connector,*`. Of course, there can be more than one connector. These MBeans have an attribute `port` from which you can query the port number.

If you use [jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) you can easily query for those attributes with

```
jmx4perl http://localhost:8080/jolokia read *:type=Connector,* port

{
  "Catalina:port=8009,type=Connector" => {
     port => 8009
  },
  "Catalina:port=8080,type=Connector" => {
     port => 8080
  }
}
```